# How to display image from SQL image table that has imagepath

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework, razor

I am working on my `MVCOnlineShop` Project, i made a product list page, now i want to show an image for each product, so i made an `image` table in `SQL`, in it `imageID` and `imagepath`, and in the `product` table i added `imageID`, i have searched on how to fetch the images from the database , but didn't understand that much, so can you please help me with my `actionresult` in my `controller`?

this is my `productList` `PartialView`:

```
@model MVCOnlineShop.Models.Category

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ProductList";
}

<script src="~/Scripts/Productjs/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/Productjs/jquery.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/Productcss/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="~/Content/Productcss/2-col-portfolio.css" rel="stylesheet">


<div class="container">

    <!-- Page Header -->
    <div class="row">
        @foreach (var Product in Model.Products)
        {
            <div class="col-md-6 portfolio-item">
                <a href="#">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/700x400" alt="">
                </a>
                <h3>
                    <a href="#">@Html.ActionLink(Product.ProductName, "Details", new { id = Product.CategoryID })</a>
                </h3>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

this view will show each product but with the same image, i want to change it to get the images in database.

**Thanks in advance :)**

Comment: Is there a foreign key relation between your "product" and "image" tables, using that "imageID"? Then your `Product` should have an Image property, with the imagepath that you want.

Comment: i added in the product table, imageID, so now every product will have 1 or more images @HansKesting

Answer (score 1):

Assuming every product has at least one image (otherwise you need to check for it's existence), and you use lazy loading in your EF model (otherwise you will need to "Include" the Images property) change this:

```
<img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/700x400" alt="">
```

into this:

```
<img class="img-responsive" src="@Product.Images.First().Imagepath" alt="">
```

You may need to change the spelling of the various properties, I had to guess at them.

Comment: should i add anything in controller?

Comment: @Ahmad if you use Entity Framework and have lazy loading enabled (it's the default) then probably not. Did you get any errors?

Comment: it says my model does not have a definition for First

Comment: Then you are missing a "using" of `System.Linq` in your view

Comment: getting this : `CS1061: 'MVCOnlineShop.Models.Image' does not contain a definition for 'First' and no extension method 'First' accepting a first argument of type 'MVCOnlineShop.Models.Image' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: Ah, I think "Image" is then not a list, but a single image. In that case you can have only one image, so you can remove that `.First()`

Comment: when i press on the category to take me to this productlist view , it took me to the code and gave this error:
`An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in App_Web_u54zbdqo.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: Then you do *not* have an image for at least one of those products. So do not use that `.Imagepath` when `Product.Image` is `null` (add some `@if` around that).

Comment: i used Product.ImageID, and i think it worked , because i am only getting image for the product id that i added to it a picture , but i am getting a picture icon, not the whole image , what is behind this?

Comment: Product.ImageID soulds like just the ID (a number), not a path to the picture. Inspect the generated HTML. Did you really add a foreign key to the database? Did you refresh the model in Visual Studio, to add that FK and Image property?

Comment: but ImageID is the link to the image table where there is an ImageID and ImagePath

Comment: Yes, therefore you need to tell the database of that link by adding a foreign key. When you then refresh your Entity Framework model (right-mouse click in editor, update from database), you get an extra navigation property for this relation.